# Iterating value of array in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have an array in Verilog given below....
array <= 100'b1000000000000000001111111100000000000000111111100001000000000000000001111110000000000000000001110000;
and I want to iterate each bit one by one and display each bit individually in console using loop or any other logic. So is it possible to do so?

Comment: Don't wanna use file handling or memreadb as i want to use this little part on Zybo... Secondly i'm using array as register in my program...

Comment: Yes, that can be done.

Comment: start with declaration of the `array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents

```
wire [99:0]val;

assign val = 100'b1000000000000000001111111100000000000000111111100001000000000000000001111110000000000000000001110000;

initial begin
 for(i=0;i<100;i=i+1)
 begin
   $display("Value is val[%d]=%d\n",i,val[i]);
 end
end
```